# How to remove frame with empty textFields?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a frame, I am using that frame to display the gender field. I have added two `textfields` in that frame, one to display gender label and other to display gender field value. When gender fields are empty Jasper is rendering empty line, I want to remove this empty line.

```
<frame>
            <reportElement key="govi" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="124" y="154" width="403" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ff3e33f8-cc51-45c3-a3ed-513832d6e180"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="141" height="15" uuid="9700c67a-9385-4dd5-8626-23a8261bc2b5"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Person with Disability ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="140" y="0" width="245" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="69f221ef-ae6b-40c6-98fd-dec7b91a6269"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified">
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{is_pd} ? "Yes" : "No")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement key="genderField" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="124" y="114" width="393" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="464b5c89-e158-4783-8f21-7b05f567e55e"/>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="104" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="0a77a60f-19ef-4634-84df-7a7f7f94ed14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{country_id} != 1 ? "Gender" : null )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="140" y="0" width="231" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="884fe0ef-654c-46e0-8399-d9fed8722a76"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{country_id} != 1 ? $F{gender} : null )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement key="govi" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="124" y="134" width="402" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="a4cbd87c-ea2d-4952-8bc4-0a7e6e655e28"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="15" uuid="e289c5be-91c4-4a74-b3d6-57c800401d0a"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Category]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="140" y="0" width="231" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c01465ce-fb3d-47ba-9c29-bdfd7be7424f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{category_id} == 1 ? "GEN" : ($F{category_id} == 2 ? "OBC" : ($F{category_id}==3 ? "SC" : "ST")))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
```

I have applied `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` on frame as well as two textfield,`isBlankWhenNull="true"` is applied on both the textfields still no success. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple to fix your issue - you should set `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` for the first *textField* (with `($F{country_id} != 1 ? "Gender" : null` epxression). In this case everything will be fine.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="104" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
    <textElement>
        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($f{country_id} != 1 ? "Gender" : null )]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I modified your template for check as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Hide frame" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="country_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="gender" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="742">
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="430" height="15" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["First line"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="60" width="430" height="15" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Third line"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <frame>
                <reportElement key="genderField" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="45" width="393" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" />
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="104" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" />
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($P{country_id} != 1 ? "Gender" : null )]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="140" y="0" width="231" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" />
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($P{country_id} != 1 ? $P{gender} : null )]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

and it works like a charm:

[image: The result in preview mode in JSS]

You get the result above for example using combinations of parameters like:

- *country_id=1*
- *gender="M"*

In case using this values:

- *country_id=3*
- *gender="F"*

the reslut will be:

[image: Case of 3 rows]

You can also simplify this fragment as at this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Hide frame" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="country_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="gender" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="742">
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="430" height="15" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["First line"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="60" width="430" height="15" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Third line"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="45" width="430" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" >
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{country_id} != 1 && $P{gender} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15" />
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{country_id} != 1 ? "Gender" : null]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="15" />
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{country_id} != 1 ? $P{gender} : null]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

In this sample the *isRemoveLineWhenBlank* and *printWhenExpression* used only for frame element.

It is works the same as this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Hide frame" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="country_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="gender" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="742">
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="430" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["First line"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="60" width="430" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Third line"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="45" width="430" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{country_id} != 1 ? "Gender" : null]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{country_id} != 1 ? $P{gender} : null]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be the same, for example in case `country_id == 1`:

[image: The result in preview mode in JSS]

***UPDATE***

You forgot to set `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` for frame with gender in your new snippet. After making this fix your new sample also works well in *iReport 5.6.0*. I replaced fields with parameters for testing purpose and change the order of frames to hide the frame with gender.

The *jrxml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Hide frame" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="country_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="gender" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="is_pd" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[true]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="category_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="742">
            <frame>
                <reportElement key="govi" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="124" y="129" width="403" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="141" height="15"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Person with Disability ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="140" y="0" width="245" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Justified">
                        <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{is_pd} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement key="genderField" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="124" y="114" width="393" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="104" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($P{country_id} != 1 ? "Gender" : null )]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="140" y="0" width="231" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($P{country_id} != 1 ? $P{gender} : null )]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement key="govi" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="124" y="97" width="402" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="15"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Category]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="140" y="0" width="231" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($P{category_id} == 1 ? "GEN" : ($P{category_id} == 2 ? "OBC" : ($P{category_id}==3 ? "SC" : "ST")))]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The design in *iReport* looks like:

[image: Design in iReport]

I set parameters like this:

- *country_id* = 1
- *gender* - empty
- *is_pd* - default value (= true)
- *category_id* - default value (=1)

The generated report for this parameters looks like:

[image: Preview in iReport]

In case using this set

- *country_id* = 2
- *gender* = "M"
- *is_pd* - default value (= true)
- *category_id* - default value (=1)

the result will be:

[image: Preview in iReport]

Comment: Not working, Still showing blank line. I have updated code snippet in question(added element which are wrapping our element). PS: I am using iReport 5.6.0

Comment: `Not working` - What do you mean? Did you check my sample on your version? Does it work?

Comment: Yeh tried both the version you've provided, none is removing white space.

Comment: Looks very strange. Ok, I'll check it with *iReport 5.6* tonight.

Comment: All versions works well in iReport 5.6.0. Did you try to set `country_id =1` and empty `gender`?

Comment: @piechuckerr I've checked your new snippet. After small fix it works also well. I've added this new sample to the answer

Comment: @AlexK Can you please check on "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796542/frame-is-taking-space-even-after-appliying-remove-line-when-blank" if anything is going wrong?