# Jasper Report dynamically generated report wrong content disposition

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm new to Jasper Report and I'm trying to generate a dynamic report. The user is presented with a dialog where he can choose which parts of the reports he wants to print.

The report is then generated using some `printWhenExpressions`. The problem is that when I hide a field, the next field is in the same place it would be if the first field would be present. I'd like to remove this offset from the top of the page and auto-adjust the elements to fill all the page from top to bottom. Also (I'm not sure it's related) sometimes I get a blank page at the end of the report.

I've tried to apply the `printWhenExpression` to the whole page but it didn't work.

This is my generated report (I'm using `iReport`):

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="650" pageHeight="1000" columnWidth="630" leftMargin="10" rightMargin="10" topMargin="10" bottomMargin="10" uuid="fa85ba06-3225-4cc2-b52c-2713413cc58d">
    <detail>
        <band height="596">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroA} || $F{quadroB} || $F{quadroC}]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="2069bd6b-05cd-4f29-8172-8007907755ee" style="title" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroA}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroA}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="90" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroA}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="150" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroA}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="210" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroA}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <break>
                <reportElement uuid="901e6fb4-1372-4977-9af8-f44d87355e50" positionType="Float" x="0" y="269" width="100" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroA} && ($F{quadroC} || $F{quadroB} || $F{quadroD} || $F{quadroE} || $F{quadroG} || $F{quadroF} || $F{quadroH} || $F{quadroI})]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b68bd828-7f67-4e4f-9ac2-be44947cde31" style="title" positionType="Float" x="0" y="270" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroB}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="300" width="630" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroB}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c1b5a9f4-19cd-4479-90ac-5146fe38505a" style="title" positionType="Float" x="0" y="372" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroC}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="392" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroC}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="442" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroC}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="491" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroC}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="cad17187-7557-4dfd-abd0-49ad5dc0cf52" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="330" width="630" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroB}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="542" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroC}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="462">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroD} || $F{quadroE}]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="22d99971-9458-4950-9669-093d1395227c" style="title" positionType="Float" x="0" y="78" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroD}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="98" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroD}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="198" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroD}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="248" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroD}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0c1eb08-9d8b-45bb-9144-6d0ee01b9a88" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="148" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroD}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <break>
                <reportElement uuid="f1ceeb7e-7d3f-4c6f-aba7-5ac8ae2dacec" positionType="Float" x="0" y="307" width="100" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroD} && ($F{quadroE} || $F{quadroG} || $F{quadroF} || $F{quadroH} || $F{quadroI})]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="fa0748f1-27d3-4b61-a032-ddfc378ae533" style="title" positionType="Float" x="0" y="308" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroE}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="47d76490-353e-4ec3-a116-a985e720d14b" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="338" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroE}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <break>
                <reportElement uuid="edad10a9-33e0-40d9-8824-a7a96d9d5f34" positionType="Float" x="0" y="417" width="100" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroE} && ($F{quadroG} || $F{quadroF} || $F{quadroH} || $F{quadroI})]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="80666213-c9fe-4744-9591-4006c8d173e7" positionType="Float" x="0" y="388" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{gianos}.isEmpty() && $F{quadroE}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <break>
                <reportElement uuid="992983d0-02df-44cc-b5a7-540bf268ec93" positionType="Float" x="0" y="59" width="100" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{quadroC} || $F{quadroB}) && ($F{quadroD} || $F{quadroE} || $F{quadroG} || $F{quadroF} || $F{quadroH} || $F{quadroI})]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
        </band>
        <band height="600">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroF} || $F{quadroG} || $F{quadroH} || $F{quadroI}]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="40f68045-80b7-462c-b147-c5a7746eb410" style="title" positionType="Float" x="0" y="144" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroG}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="5af4dc78-6286-4989-af44-ab07a58ac73e" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="174" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroG}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <break>
                <reportElement uuid="4a8df3d1-3b15-4139-98a4-3fad4ed8f348" positionType="Float" x="0" y="244" width="100" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{quadroG} || $F{quadroF}) && ($F{quadroH} || $F{quadroI})]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="170bd6d6-81a1-4bed-ab93-840798edbc0b" style="title" positionType="Float" x="0" y="254" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroH}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="fc6308d0-d919-4aa3-9a0e-9acfdbe1d793" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="284" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroH}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <break>
                <reportElement uuid="9ef198b2-5d32-4a6a-bc23-c87c31af7021" positionType="Float" x="0" y="354" width="100" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroH} && $F{quadroI}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1ccd2dd4-83c2-4e69-a806-8adb7279bf4e" style="title" positionType="Float" x="0" y="364" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroI}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="a6f3ace1-27ac-4b55-8005-c7cfbcc2d74c" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="394" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroI}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="4fcd31f2-d6f6-49e5-a14f-ffd23070f383" positionType="Float" x="0" y="224" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{smt}.isEmpty() && $F{quadroG}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b3ae5054-a5a0-4068-a614-3218b9663c70" positionType="Float" x="0" y="334" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{r}.isEmpty() && $F{quadroH}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="77a933cf-c457-45db-9576-053c4c692fd5" positionType="Float" x="0" y="98" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{e}.isEmpty() && $F{quadroF}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="71aa9131-7ff8-4d32-932d-f58876bb3871" positionType="Float" x="0" y="444" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{r}.isEmpty() && $F{quadroI}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="25b337a0-acca-4ffa-96eb-251e8a507246" style="title" positionType="Float" x="0" y="18" width="630" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroF}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="77660a36-1c0f-4c56-b04c-13cdd0ca7c80" key="subreport" positionType="Float" x="0" y="48" width="630" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{quadroF}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Could anyone tell if there's a property I can set to achieve this behaviour?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I've already tried the solution in the duplicate question suggestion (as you can see I have already set `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` on each element) but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071943/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-textfield-in-jasperreports) & [How to remove frame with empty textFields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41178070/876298)

Comment: You can solve the issue with *positionType*

Comment: @AlexK any element of the report (except the first one) has positionType set to Variable which to my understanding is what I should go for. Also, I've already tried the solution in the question you suggested as you can see in my report but they didn't work

Comment: You should post small, minimal *jrxml* to reproduce the problem. Your current *jrxml* is huge. The *positionType* + *printWhen* are always solve this task

Comment: @AlexK As I said I'm new to Jasper reports. I don't know what exactly is causing this behavior and if I did I wouldn't have posted it here. I've removed the footer, the header and the properties because I think they are not related (but I'm not 100% sure). Also, as you can see I have both positionType = Variable and printWhen conditions set already but the problem is still there

Comment: It is impossible to check your template - you have a lot of subreports at it

Comment: @AlexK yeah I do since this report is itself a template for other subreports. I've removed the subreports expressions and left only the report element with the print when to make it slimmer